# Unable to delete whitespace from string with tr, sed

Tags: sed, utf-8, character-encoding, removing-whitespace, tr

I have a file that contains a whitespace character that I'm not able to successfully remove with command-line tools such as `tr` or `sed`. Here's the input:

```
2,  78  ,, 1
6,    74, ,1
```

and I want the output to look like:

```
2,78,,1
6,74,,1
```

**Attempts**

If I try `tr -d "[[:space:]]` the result is `2, 78,,16,74,,1` which leaves a space character and removes the newline.

If I try `sed 's/[[:space:]]//g'` the result is

```
2, 78,,1
6,74,,1
```

which still leaves the space.
I converted the string to hex, and it seems the offending character is `a0`, but even then the results are not what I'd expect:
`sed 's/\xa0//g'` yields

```
2, �78  ,, 1
6,    74, ,1
```

**Question**

What is that whitespace character that is not getting caught by the `[[:space:]]` character class? How can I delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [offending character](https://superuser.com/questions/517847/use-sed-to-replace-nbsp-160-hex-00a0-octal-240-non-breaking-space) is a UTF-8-encoded non-breaking space, with hex representation `\xc2\xa0`. You can remove all spaces, including non-breaking spaces, with

```
sed -E 's/[[:space:]]|\xc2\xa0//g'
```

**Explanation**

- `-E` turns on extended regex to allow the `|` to represent logical OR
- `'s/pattern/replacement/'` substitutes pattern matches with the replacement text (in this case, an empty string), with `/g` repeating the pattern substitution multiple times per line
- `[[:space:]]` matches most whitespace characters, including spaces and tabs
- `\xc2\xa0` is the hex code for the UTF-8 non-breaking space

Answer (score 0):

The characters you want to remove are the non-printable ones (i.e the ones not in the `[:print:]` character class) rather than the ones just the ones in the `[:space:]` character class:

```
$ printf 'foo\xc2\xa0bar\n' > file
$ cat file
foo bar
$ tr -dc '[:print:]' < file
foobar$
```

but I notice the equivalent doesn't work in GNU sed or GNU awk and idk why.

Comment: This doesn't work for multi-line input, as it removes the newlines. For single-line input, I agree that you could chain `tr`, as in `tr -dc '[:print:]' | tr -d '[:space:]'`